# Warning when I click a button that could have been pressed through a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, monitoring, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a program that can display a warning whenever I click a button that could have been pressed through a keyboard shortcut.

Ideally, the warning should just be some pop-up that automatically disappears after a few seconds. (I don't want to have to click on something each time to remove it)

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Gratis is preferable.

Comment: On Mac, Cheatsheet is awesome.  For Windows, the closest I've found is Keyrocket - and it sucks ( at least in scope ) - that is why this is a comment, and not answer; because it's not an answer.